# Jqueryui and cookie status

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

I have got these code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Toggle</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.lywomen.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; }
    #button { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
    #effect { width: 240px; height: 135px; padding: 0.4em; position: relative; }
    #effect h3 { margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
        //run the currently selected effect
        function runEffect(){
            //get effect type from
            var selectedEffect = 'slide';

            //most effect types need no options passed by default
            var options = {};
            //check if it's scale or size - they need options explicitly set
            if(selectedEffect == 'scale'){  options = {percent: 0}; }
            else if(selectedEffect == 'size'){ options = { to: {width: 200,height: 60} }; }

            //run the effect
            jQuery("#effect").toggle(selectedEffect,options,500);

        };

        //set effect from select menu value
        jQuery("#button").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("clickedbuttons")
            runEffect();
            return false;
        });

    });
    </script>

<div class="demo">

<div class="toggler">
    <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Toggle</h3>
        <p>
            Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</a>
</div><!-- End demo -->

</body>

</html>
```

and its slide effect show and hide i want it like vbulletin.com/forum

when you click hide its still hiddin until you clicked show that save for your user choice

so i found this link it was really help full

http://www.devcomments.com/q465701/jquery-and-cookie-status

but its different of my effect slide can you just please mange the codes to be save the cookies as that code please im using vbulletin too

you can check that link

www.lywomen.com/f

its my forum you can see the left sidebar i would like to give the choice for to hide and show for it

please and please help me

and thanks a lots

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5scYJ/

I created this fiddle to look at it better. So, do you want an option to have users always hide the sidebar (in a profile page or settings page for example)? Because, otherwise, your code seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

check that link

http://www.devcomments.com/q465701/jquery-and-cookie-status

you can find the code works with vbulletin can you mange it please to work with my code the simple example i have put the html page

thank you